# Intalio: Difference between 4 ways of adding a form to a process

Tags: forms, init, notify, business-process-management

I made a form using Intalio's AJAX Widget tool but I was confused once I wanted to add the form to a user's pool.

I actually followed [this tutorial](http://bpms.intalio.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/03_OrderRequest_Tutorial.swf) from Intalio's website. In the 5th slide, they mentioned the ways of adding the form (initProcess, create and complete, notify, escalate):

[image: use priorite.gi for initProcess / create and complete / notify / escalate]

but no further explanations were given.

So, I would like to know the differences between each one of these ways and when should I use one way and not the other.

Comment: http://bpms.intalio.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/03_OrderRequest_Tutorial.swf - link is dead (and probably was flash anyway, and flash is dead).

Answer (score 0):

You use the initProcess if that form will actually kick off a process. Doing so will show a new entry on the web site front end in the Workflow>Processes category. It's what you can see in slide 6. Connect the form to the process.

Use create and complete if you want to give a user or group of users a task to complete. This shows up in the Workflow>Tasks section on the website. It locks your process until a user completes the task or a deadline is hit.

Use notify if you want to send a form as a notification to a user. This shows up in the Workflow>Notifications section. User can only dismiss it. It does not lock you process. It basically just triggers the notification and moves on.

You can use escalate to reassign an existing form to another user or group. This basically sits between the create and complete part of the form, gets triggered by an external message/event and lets you reassign the form.

Hope this helps. Cheers.