# Deploy workflow processes in intalio server

Tags: deployment, process, bpmn, workflow-activity, business-process-management

I'm done building processes and intended to deploy into intalio server. it already success deployed,but the form that I've been develops using ajax form did not append to the workflow processes. anyone knows how to make that form appear on workflow processes?

both several task such as init process and create or complete already done. I've been assign role in workflow too. i create three types of form. submit form, validate form, and processing form. and the role was student, department, and academic.

the submit form already shows in monitoring workflow. and when I assign module to the specific user, in this case student, it already works. however, the rest of form (validate form and processing form) does not appear both in monitoring workflow and after assign to department and academic it doesnt not appear.

I think the process actually almost the same like the intalio tutorial. rite now, I make the user only two, student and department to make sure that the submit form and validate form run smoothly. but still, the validate form doesnt appear.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you go into Administration>Monitoring>Processes. Can you see any of the processes in the Failed state? It sounds like the process is either failing or not getting to the point where that form would be triggered.

You can click on the number in that column and it takes you to a list of failed instances, or click on the number in the in progress column to get to instances still running. Click on the text in the Process column to get at the actual error. You can also see a diagram of the instance, this sometimes help to figure out where exactly it failed (clicking on the little gears in top left on the diagram colors the tasks that have been executed to green)

Hope this helps.
Cheers.

Comment: hi, sorry for the late reply. i've been update my description. you may can read them again. i wonder, what do you mean with notify part. I guess I need your idea how notify must be work. seems its important part that i skip. thanks

Comment: I've answered a question about the 4 ways to use a form in Intalio here if you want to have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29163544/intalio-difference-between-4-ways-of-adding-a-form-to-a-process/29818256#29818256